# Advice for first time DM/player with first time hero players trying the Lost Mine of Phandelver with an under-sized party

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, lost-mine-of-phandelver, group-scaling

After listening to and enjoying some "actual play" podcasts I'm about to try DnD with my wife and children. None of us have played before, so after some research I've decided to go with the official DnD 5e starter set.

Due to a slight misunderstanding I thought that the set was fine for four players including the DM, it seems that actually it's meant for a party of four or five plus the DM.

Given that the party will only be three strong, none of them have played before, and two of them are children I would expect them to not be hugely effective to begin with.

As DM I'm planning to help as much as I can with the rules and hints about what they can do (initially they won't have read all the rules). But I'm concerned that as a small party they might struggle.

The kids have decided that they like the wizard and rogue and my wife is happy to play any of the remaining characters. From my research I've suggested the cleric for her so that they have someone with high AC and good healing.

As I haven't played before either I'm looking for suggestions on what else I can do to get things off to a good start. Obviously I can do things like reduce the number of enemies in fights, but I assume that there are a lot of other tricks that I'm not aware of to help in this kind of situation.

Comment: Related, may contain a dupe: [Is it possible to play the D&D Starter Set with fewer than recommended players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71926/52137), [How can I tweak the Lost Mine of Phandelver for only 2 player characters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119464/52137), [Should I adjust the Starting Encounter for Lost Mines of Phandelver for this party?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/149366/52137)

Comment: I just realized that LMoP does not have a paladin, so my suggested answer is dead.  Question: is there a fourth close friend/relative who could join as the Fighter?(If your wife is the cleric, which is a great choice).   (I am guessing "no" but i figured I'd ask).  There is a resource [here for free that you may find useful as a DM](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=165)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Unfortunately, your question is hardly answerable in its current state and needs to be more focused. You haven't played yet, and we do not know what problems will you face (having 3 players instead of 4 probably is the lesser one). I suggest rather than try to anticipate any number of potential problems, try your session and ask us about any problems you do experience.

Comment: @enkryptor he's trying to get ahead of it so that there won't be problems.  He's playing with his wife and kids.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast unfortunately, no there isn't a fourth player available at the moment

Comment: Thanks @Someone_Evil I'd seen some of those questions, but not all of them.

Comment: @Dan How old the kids are?

Comment: @enkryptor 9 and 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Four things you can do besides tweak encounter difficulty

1. Emphasize exploration and social interactions during the first few sessions.  Make combat a bit more rare (ignore the 6-8 encounters per adventure day guidance in the Basic Rules, you are playing with beginners).   Some of the encounters don't need combat.  Coaching/nudging non combat solutions to some of the encounters with NPCs can make for some fun play.
2. Equip each character with a free healing potion from an NPC before starting out. (That's more or less an insurance policy).
3. Call for die rolls only when you have to.
   Combat calls for quite a few die rolls, and some ability checks in the published adventure need to be rolled, like picking the locks on locked chests.
4. Err in favor of the players.

   That's how I started my kids out about 20 years ago with Basic D&D (25th anniversary edition/big box). My wife only played a few sessions (oddly enough, also a cleric) but she also got a benefit from that approach.

#### Focus on "[How to Play](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=4)"

1. DM describes situation
2. Players tell you what they intend to do
   Have them tell you, {and then, if there's something on the character sheet that is a good fit, coach them to and through it}.
3. DM narrates the outcome

For tweaking the combat encounters: [use the free Basic Rules (starting on Page 165) from WoTC](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=165) to adjust encounters to Medium/Easy range at first.

#### [Chapter 7 "Help" with Ability Checks](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=62)

The linked rules paragraph is entitled "Working Together."
For ability checks: encourage the players to narrate a help action when one of the other two attempts an ability check.  This does two things.

1. It encourages team work as a mind set,
2. it also offers advantage to an ability check which increases chances
   of success (roll 2d20, pick the better score)

   More successes more often, especially with kids, is a good way to sustain engagement.  This I've found to be a bonus even with experienced players for this edition.  Get them *to play as a team*; the Help action rewards teamwork mechanically.

I would suggest getting a close friend or relative to play the Fighter, but you note in a comment that there isn't such a player available.  If that changes, I'd still recommend it.

#### Option if it becomes available: "Phone a Friend"

Why?  The Action economy in this edition of the game starts to get a little wonky when there are fewer PCs.   When in doubt, default to one less monster/NPC, since the players as a team are getting 25% fewer actions or choices, when combat comes in the situation where there are 3 rather than 4 PCs.

Comment: Thanks, our first session went well, we did a lot of of option 1, and got to the end of the first combat. I cut out one of the 4 attackers and overall it worked well.
Having the "How to Play" steps to hand helped, as did printing out an extra copy of each of their character sheets.

Comment: @Dan glad to hear you enjoyed it, best wishes going forward. :-)